# How to output consecutive values in a CFLOOP

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfloop

I would like to output two numbers consecutively:

- Number one

- Number two

Below is the basic code:

```
  <cfloop index="x"  from="2" to="#ListLen(stringOf200Numbers)#" >
          <cfset x2 = x>
          <cfoutput>
             <h2>#x#</h2>
             <h2>#x2#</h2>
             </br>
         </cfoutput>
  </cfloop>
```

I have tried many different angles.. would love some expert assistance...

Comment: Please don't simply say "you've tried many different angles", please *show us* the different angles so we know what ground you've already covered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the next index in the loop is going to be... `x+1`, isn't it? So the first entry in `stringOf200Numbers` is going to be `listGetAt(stringOf200Numbers, x)`, and the second one is going to be `listGetAt(stringOf200Numbers, x+1)`. Be careful at the end of the loop though... there will not be an x+1 entry for the last list position.